# Android Studio. MyApp Unfortunately has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to get the current location (latitude and longtitude) and my app is not running. I have  a TextView to view the longtitude (testing for a start).
This is my mainActivity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    //public Location location;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //creating new object of the method
       MyLocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        double longt=myLocationListener.getLocation().getLongitude();
        String longi =String.valueOf(longt);
        //String lat1 =String.valueOf(lat);
        tv.setText(longi);
        //myLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(WIFI_SERVICE);
        //myLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(WIFI_SERVICE);
       // myLocationListener.getLatitude(location);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void process(View view){
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and these errors came up:

>

```
 8585-8585/com.example.maxi.try_v2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.maxi.try_v2, PID: 8585
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maxi.try_v2/com.example.maxi.try_v2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.maxi.try_v2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if you can help, I would be glad.

this is the MyLocationListener class (sorry for the incomplete info)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;



/**
 * Created by maxi on 7/17/15.
 */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private Context mContext;
    //gps status flag
    boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    //flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled;
    //min distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    //min time between updates in miliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 60000; //1min
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public static double latitude;
    public static double longtitude;
    Location location;

    /* public MyLocationListener(Context context){
         this.mContext = context;
         getLocation();
     }*/
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longtitude = loc.getLongitude();

    }

    public void getLatitude(Location loc) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        Log.w("poutsa", lat);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.w("myApp", "no network");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.w("myApp", "NetIsOn");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener
        // .html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //gettin GPS status
            isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            //gettin network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                //no network
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                //first get location from provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (isGpsEnabled){
                    if (location == null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Gps Enabled","Gps Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null){
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your MyLocationListener code? Seems like you don't get the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is giving you a `NullPointerException`, which means you're getting null when making a request to the Location

```
double longt=myLocationListener.getLocation().getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.maxi.try_v2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)

Open *MainActivity.java*, look at line 27: you have a `null` variable.

Since you did not tell what line 27 is, I cannot help any more.

**Just check for `null`s, for example: `myLocationListener.getLocation()` might be `null` in your code.**